# WordPress - Breadcrumb NavXT issue with categories

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, breadcrumbs

I am having some major issues with this plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/installation/

I have this layout to my site. In my functions.php file, I have created some new categories inside 'Products' using the following code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_product_cat_scaffolding' );

function create_product_cat_scaffolding() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'ScaffoldingProducts',
        'products',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Scaffolding Products' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'scaffoldingproducts' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            )
        );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_product_cat_fencing' );

function create_product_cat_fencing() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'FencingHoardings',
        'products',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Fencing Hoardings' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'fencinghoardings' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            )
        );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_product_cat_groundworks' );

function create_product_cat_groundworks() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'Groundworks',
        'products',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Groundworks' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'groundworks' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            )
        );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_product_cat_Safety' );

function create_product_cat_Safety() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'Safety',
        'products',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Safety' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'safety' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            )
        );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_product_cat_access' );

function create_product_cat_access() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'Access',
        'products',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Access' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'access' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            )
        );
}
```

Which creates the following:

[image]

From here, I have added sub categories to each of these, for example:

[image]

And then when I create products, I just select which sub category they apply to.

Now - my issue. When I click onto my Safety page, the plugin works fine, it goes:

**My Site > Safety**

But then If I click onto a sub category from Safety, such as Safety category, instead of the breadcrumb going to:

**My Site > Safety > Safety Category**

It goes to

**My Site > Safety**

Does anyone have any ideas?

In the plugin, the settings there is an option for Taxonomies, which shows this:

```
<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" title="Go to the %title% Safety archives." href="%link%">%htitle%</a></span>
```

Comment: OR and alternative which would suit my needs would be appreciated!

Comment: Breadcrumbs in Yoast SEO perhaps? http://kb.yoast.com/article/245-implement-wordpress-seo-breadcrumbs

Comment: Have you create custom category page in theme ? like. `taxonomy-ScaffoldingProducts.php`, `taxonomy-Safety.php`, `taxonomy-FencingHoardings.php` , `taxonomy-Groundworks.php`,  `taxonomy-Access.php`, `ScaffoldingProducts.php`, `Safety.php`,  `FencingHoardings.php`, `Groundworks.php` and `Access.php` all

Comment: Hi Hemal, 

I have them category pages :)

Comment: Anyone?

This has had more than 100 views

Comment: Still nothing - Can't even add more bounty to this?

Comment: Do I start a new question? My bounty has gone but still no answer

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps

```
 go to Setting > Permalinks > Select Custom Structure
 add this into textbox /%category%/postname
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

Control what's happened in Breadcrumb-NavXT/class.bcn_breadcrumb_trail.php at fill() function line 855.

```
else if(is_archive())
{
    $type = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    //For date based archives
    if(is_date())
    {
        $this->do_archive_by_date();
    }
    else if(is_post_type_archive() && !isset($type->taxonomy))
    {
        $this->do_archive_by_post_type();
    }
    //For taxonomy based archives
    else if(is_category() || is_tag() || is_tax())
    {
        $this->do_archive_by_term();
    }
    $this->type_archive($type);
}
```

Comment: So like this? 

  if(count($this->breadcrumbs) > 0)

  {

   //Exit early since we have breadcrumbs in the trail

   return NULL;

  }
  else if(is_archive())
{
    $type = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    //For date based archives
    if(is_date())
    {
        $this->do_archive_by_date();
    }
    else if(is_post_type_archive() && !isset($type->taxonomy))
    {
        $this->do_archive_by_post_type();
    }
    //For taxonomy based archives
    else if(is_category() || is_tag() || is_tax())
    {
        $this->do_archive_by_term();
    }
    $this->type_archive($type);
}

Comment: If I am at home - Category, and click a sub category, IT then goes  Home - Sub Category - Sub Category